# .contains in jquery not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, contains

I have used `.contains` function in jquery to see whether a string is present in an `array`.

In chrome browser this functionality is not working. I have tested in firefox, it is working properly. Is there any other approach to check for a string is contained in an array.
code:

```
if(array.contains(verifyString))
   alert("Already existing");
 else
   alert("No string found");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer [indexOf() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) if it's only to compare string to string.
This function is native for Array object and IE supporte it well.

```
var res = array.indexOf(verifyString);
if(res > -1){
 alert("Already existing");
} else {
   alert("No string found");
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d5n41toq/)

Answer (score 3):

As you've tagged this question with jQuery, you can use the `$.inArray` helper:

```
if ($.inArray(verifyString, array) > -1) {
    alert('Already existing');
}
else {
    alert('No string found');
}
```

Note that `-1` is returned when the specified value is not contained within the array, otherwise it will return the index of the found item.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this (-1 if the value does not exsists): array.indexOf("String");

Example: var array = ["test", "test1", "test2"];

```
array.indexOf("test") - it returns 0
array.indexOf("test1") - it returns 1
array.indexOf("test3") - it returns -1
```

There is no need to use jQuery.

Comment: can you please give a sample code for using it in jquery, I am anewbie. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I added an example. You can find more inofrmation about it on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp